# BackupExec 12 + RALUS - VERY slow backups

Tags: performance, backupexec

We use Backup Exec 12 and the Remote Agent for Linux/Unix Servers (RALUS) to backup a large
RHEL5 system. For various reasons we need to do a daily working set job. These working-set jobs run abysmally slow. The link between the target machine and the BE server is gigabit, and any other type of job runs 1-3GB/min. These working-set jobs start out at perhaps 40MB/min and over the course of the backup job slowly drops down so low that the BE job rate display in the "current jobs" goes blank.. Since we usually are only doing changed-files for one day, the job is usually small and finishes overnight and we don't worry abotu the slowness, but we had some issues with the backup server, and missed about 6 days of fairly heavy work on the Linux box, so this working-set job will be a doozy.. We have support with Symantec, and I've pestered them a lot about this, they've had me run RALUS in debug mode, sent them that log and a VXgather from the BE host and they had no fix/workaround.. To give an idea, I have the mentioned working-set job running for the last 3 1/2 hours and it's backed up just under 10MEGAbytes.... I'm posting this here to see if anybody in the "real world" has seen this/and/or has any ideas what might be causing these abysmally slow jobs, since Symantec seems to be clueless...

Comment: I think we have to deal with same problems. Have you found a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Examine the system resources of the target machine while backing up. Locate the bottleneck that way.

I am using an older version of backupexec. Are you only backing up files, or is there some level of abstraction for backing up services like databases?